# Joint 0.5.5 / mongo mapper 0.8.6 - NoMethodError (undefined method `etag' for #<GridIO ...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rubygems, mongomapper, etag

We use

- Rails 2.3.8
- Ruby 1.9.2
- Mongo mapper 0.8.6
- Joint 0.5.5
- Wand 0.4

We are getting this error when using etag in this following line of code:

```
return  if fresh_when( :etag => @lesson.video.etag, :last_modified => @lesson.updated_at.utc )
```

===

```
Processing LessonsController#video to mp4 (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-22 20:32:51) [GET]
Parameters: {"subdomains"=>["www"], "controller"=>"lessons", "action"=>"video",  "id"=>"4ccf79526905582045000041", "format"=>"mp4"}

NoMethodError (undefined method `etag' for #<GridIO _id: 4ccf846a1204cc1b2f0000e9>):  
joint (0.5.5) lib/joint/attachment_proxy.rb:32:in `method_missing'
app/controllers/lessons_controller.rb:71:in `video'
```

Here is the Lesson class:

```
class Lesson
  include MongoMapper::Document
  plugin Joint

  (other stuff...)

  attachment :image                                                            
  attachment :video                                                            

  timestamps!                                                                  
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

-Mei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mei, please use the hash [] method to get the etag attribute:

`@lesson.video['etag']`